# osm.pbf in JOSM editor not working

Tags: openstreetmap, josm, pbf

I create lines in JOSM Editor and while saving it to osm format it works well. saving and reopening it , but for saving it in osm.pbf format it works but in  reopening it, I get this error [image]

Comment: You may have written data to the file that has not been uploaded to the server. Until then, new elements have negative IDs. Pbf might not expect unsaved data.

Comment: ok, this file *.osm.pbf work fine on the osrm route server and thats too good for me